# Use Latest Version of Python 3 When Launching IDLE

Tags: homebrew, python-3.6, python-idle

I used homebrew to install a new version of Python3 on my Mac. The version I installed is Python 3.7.

When I launch "idle3" from terminal, the shell still displays "Python 3.6.0 Shell" at the top of the window.

Is there some way to configure idle to "use" the latest version of Python 3 that I installed using Homebrew?

Answer (score 0):

The version of idle3 provided by homebrew is located in `/usr/local/bin`. This location should appear first in your `PATH`.

Edit your `~/.bash_profile` file and add at the end:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```